# HTML 5 form to PHP email script sends blank email with undefined variable error

Tags: html, php

I am new to both HTML 5 and especially PHP, I have been trying to get a test email sent to me with the information in the form. I get a blank email and when checking the Apache logs it shows undefined variable from the PHP form handler.

HTML form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formstyleb.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>

<body>
<form action="formemail.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain" id="contact">
   <fieldset>
     <legend>Your Contact Details:</legend>
<div>
<label for="author">Name:(Required)</label>
<input name="author" class="required name" id="author" type="text"
title="Please Enter Your Name!">
</div>

   <div>
<label for="email">Email Address:(Required)</label>
<input name="email"class="required email" id="email" type="text"
title="Please Enter a Valid email Address!">
</div>

 <div>
<label for="comment">Comment:</label>
<textarea rows="12" id="message" name="comment"></textarea> 
</div>
<div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit as Multipart/form-data">
        <img src="submit1.jpg" alt="Submit">
    </button>

</div>
<div>
    <button type="reset" id="reset">
        <img src="resetrs.jpg" alt="reset">
    </button>

</div>

   </fieldset>
 </form> 

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jqformval.js"></script>

 </body>

 </html>
```

PHP handler:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
/*stops undefined index error*/
if(isset($_POST['email'],$_POST['author'],$_POST['comment'] )) {


    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $author = $_POST['author'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $comment = wordwrap($comment, 70);
 }
     $email_from = 'xxxx@yyyy.com';
     $email_subject = "Form Submission";
     $email_body = "Message from $author.\n".
     "The message reads:\n $comment".

    $to = "xxxx@yyyy.com";
    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
    mail($to,$email_subject,$comment,$headers);

      header( "Location: Thank You.html" );
 ?>
```

Comment: no surprise, you build `$email_body` and then never use it. the rest of your $_POST-based vars are only defined if certain conditions are met, but even if the conditions AREN'T met, you still send the email.

Comment: Your `mail` function is not using `$email_body`, but `$comment`

Comment: Use `$_POST['message']` not `$_POST['comment']` you should reference the id and not the name

Comment: Thank you all. I finally figured out why the code would work using GET method but not with POST. I had to remove from the HTML form : enctype="text/plain"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about fixing the php file's if condition.. it may have the problem, try fixing it to: -

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// and add the name="submit" to the submit button

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $author = $_POST['author'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $comment = wordwrap($comment, 70);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```
$email = "";
$author = "";
$visitor_email = "";
$comment = "";
```

at the beginning of your script.

Also I'm wondering if you are intending to send the email even if information is not being supplied. If that is the case then the

```
 $comment = $_POST['comment'];
 $comment = wordwrap($comment, 70);
```

Should move outside of the if.... if you want to only send if all of the information is supplied then you need to move everything else into the if

Comment: I have found that using the GET method and then using $_REQUST[] I get an email sent with content?

Comment: If this solved you problem accept the answer by clicking on the checkbox. that way the next guy that has this problem knows what worked.